# how to delete the data in sql database when closing the browser asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new here, may know how to delete the data in database when closing the browser in asp.net? Example: when the user close the browser, want to  delete some record automatically at SQL server.Is it Possible?

home.aspx

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(window).unload(function () {
                $.aja(angry)
                    {
                        type:"Post",
                        url:"logout.aspx",
                    })
                });
        });
    </script>
```

logout.aspx.vb

```
 Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim myDataReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim mySQL As String
    Dim myComm As SqlCommand
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection

    mySQL = "Delete from dbo.CheckLogin where @UserId = UserId"
    myConn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(Session("ConnString")))
    myConn.Open()

    myComm = New SqlCommand(mySQL, myConn)
    myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Session("loginid"))
    myDataReader = myComm.ExecuteReader()

    WelMsg.Text = ""
    Session.Clear()






End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you try?

Comment: when i closed the browser, the data still there. It doesn't delete the data at sql server.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem or not, but it might be worth trying a GET rather than a POST.  I just don't remember if the Page_Load method gets called on a POST.  It probably does, but still it's worth a try.  You should debug a little bit to see where in the code things are going wrong.  Is your Ajax call executing?  Is your server-side Page_Load method getting called?

Comment: "The exact handling of the unload event has varied from version to version of browsers. For example, some versions of Firefox trigger the event when a link is followed, but not when the window is closed. In practical usage, behavior should be tested on all supported browsers, and contrasted with the proprietary beforeunload event." mentioned [here](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is really a bad approach and secondly it will not work. When the browser is closed, the web page cannot make a round trip to the server and make request to run sql query. At the most you can handle some browser events and some some clean up on the client side. Can you give more details on what are you trying to achieve? Looking at the code, I would suggest, you do the 'delete' when the user logs out from the site or you can store the user session in the database and maybe create some server side jobs which will cleanup the data if user is not active. Makes sense?

Comment: I already implemented the delete function at logout. The reason i want to implement this is because using table to store the userid. To prevent multiple login with same id.

Comment: Why dont you capture the browser close event and redirect user to logout page?

Comment: Can show me how to do? The browser closed still can redirect?